# How to set collection name attribute for org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.Document annotation value using env variable or property value?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-firestore, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Cloud Firestore. And i want to map object to collection using @Document annotation

```
@Document(collectionName = "usersCollection")
public class User {
}
```

But i need to have different collection name depends on environment(We are using one gcp project for dev, stage and prod environments and I need to have "usersCollectionDev", "usersCollectionStage" and "usersCollectionProd" collections for example).

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem, because firestore instance is the same for entire project